# String Tokenization problem occurs when deleting duplicate words from a string

Tags: c, string, duplicates, tokenize, strtok

What I'm trying to do in the following code is to tokenize a string and store every token in a dynamic allocated structure but exclude any duplicates.

This code kind of works, until I enter a string that contains two equal words. For example, the string "this this", will also store the second word even though it's the same.  But if I enter "this this is" instead, it removes the second "this", and completely ignores the last word of the string, so that it doesn't get deleted if there's a duplicate in the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define dim 70


typedef struct string {
  char* token[25];
} string;

int main() {

  string* New = malloc(dim*sizeof(string));

  char* s;
  char* buffer = NULL;
  int i = 0, r = 0;

  s = malloc(dim * sizeof(char));

  fgets(s, dim, stdin);

  printf("The string is: %s\n", s); 

  New->token[i] = malloc(dim*sizeof(char));
  New->token[i] = strtok(s, " ");
  ++i;

  while((buffer = strtok(NULL, " ")) && buffer != NULL){

    printf("\nbuffer is: %s", buffer);

    for(r = 0; r < i; ++r) {

      if(strcmp(New->token[r], buffer) != 0 && r == i-1) {

        New->token[i] = malloc(strlen(buffer)*sizeof(char)+1);
        New->token[i] = buffer;
        ++i;

      }
      else if(New->token[r] == buffer) {
            break;
      }

    }



  }

printf("\n New string: ");
for(i = 0; New->token[i] != NULL; ++i) {
   printf(" %s", New->token[i]);
}


return 0;
}
```

In my mind this should work fine but I'm really having a hard time finding what I did wrong here. If you need additional info just ask me please, I apologise for any eventual lack of clarity (and for my english).

Comment: Have you tried printing the `New->token` array at each step, to see its contents and how the program interacts with it? `strtok()` modifies the tokenized string as it progresses, and that would definitely interfere with the output in the `for` loop of `New->token[0]`.

Comment: Please apply some consistent indentation to your shown code.

Comment: @xing I added `\n` to the delimiters but nothing changes. Also, should I change `New->token[i] = malloc(...` and `New->token[i] = strtok(s, " ");` using the  `strcpy()` function?

Comment: `sizeof(char) == 1` - _always_.  So `s = malloc(dim * sizeof(char));` becomes `s = malloc(dim);`

Comment: The steps I see: 1) enter a string containing several space delimited sub-strings. 2) parse string into array of sub-strings. 3) do not allow duplicates in the final collection of sub-strings.  If this is what you need to do, there are simpler ways.  Are you required to use dynamic allocation?  Is the use of a struct required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete re-write of this answer to address some fundamentally wrong things I did not see the first time through.  See in-line comments in the code at bottom to explain some of the construct changes:

I ran your code exactly as is and saw what you are describing, and other than the note about using `strcmp` in the other answer, found several lines of code that can be adjusted, or removed to make it do what you described it should:

First, the struct definition creates a pointer to an array of char.  Based on what you are doing later in the code, what you need is a simple array of char

```
typedef struct string {
  //char* token[25]; //this create a pointer to array of 25 char
  char token[25]; //this is all you need
} string;
```

As you will see later, this will greatly simplify memory allocation.

some basic problems:

Include the `\n` newline character in your parsing delimiter.  When `<enter>` is hit as the end of entering the string, a newline is appended, causing the first instance of `this` and the second instance of `this\n` to be unequal.

```
while((buffer = strtok(NULL, " \n")) && buffer != NULL){
                               ^^
```

This line is creating uninitialized memory.

```
string* New = malloc(dim*sizeof(string));
```

A note about using *[malloc()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm)* vs. *[calloc()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm)*: *malloc()* leaves the memory it creates uninitialized, while *calloc()* creates a block of memory all initialized to `0`.

Memory created using `malloc()`

[image]

Memory created using `calloc()`:

[image]

This becomes important in several places in your code, but in particular I see a problem in the last section:

```
for(i = 0; New->token[i] != NULL; ++i) {
   printf(" %s", New->token[i]);
}
```

If the memory created for `New` is not initialized, you can get a run-time error when the index `i` is incremented beyond the area in memory that you have explicitly written to, and loop attempts to test `New->token[i]`.  If `New->token[i]` contains anything but `0`, it will attempt to print that area of memory.

You should also free each instance of memory created in your code with a corresponding call to *[free()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm)*.

All of this, and more is addressed in the following re-write of your code:
(tested against *this is a string a string*.)

```
typedef struct string {
  //char* token[25]; //this create a pointer to array of 25 char
  char token[25]; //this is all you need
} string;

int main() {
    char* s;
    char* buffer = NULL;
    int i = 0, r = 0;

    string* New = calloc(dim, sizeof(string));//Note: This creates an array of New.
                                              //Example: New[i]
                                              //Not: New->token[i]
    s = calloc(dim , sizeof(char));
    fgets(s, dim, stdin);
    printf("The string is: %s\n", s); 
    buffer = strtok(s, " \n");
    strcpy(New[i].token, buffer); //use strcpy instead of = for strings
    //restuctured the parsing loop to a more conventional construct
    // when using strtok:
    if(buffer)
    {
        ++i;
        while(buffer){
            printf("\nbuffer is: %s", buffer);
            for(r = 0; r < i; ++r) {
                if(strcmp(New[r].token, buffer) != 0 && r == i-1) {
                    strcpy(New[i].token, buffer);
                    ++i;
                }
                else if(strcmp(New[r].token, buffer)==0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            buffer = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n New string: ");
    for(i = 0; i<dim; i++) {
        if(New[i].token) printf(" %s", New[i].token);
    }
    free(New);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand the use of `calloc()` now and it fixed the first problem I had with this code. Still, the code doesn't behave as intended when I type in something like "_this is a string a string_" because it prints the same given string without removing anything.

Comment: @Waco - I need to edit my answer.  I discovered several other problems that I would like to address.  It will be posted in a few minutes.

Comment: @Waco - I made significant changes, some of which you may not understand. See in-line comments for explanations.  Ask in comments if you have other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You comparing pointers instead of comparing strings. Replace

```
  }
  else if(New->token[r] == buffer) {
        break;
```

With

```
  }
  else if(strcmp(New->token[r], buffer) == 0) {
        break;
```

You also need to copy the buffer:

```
memcpy(New->token[i],buffer,strlen(buffer)+1);
```

instead of

```
New->token[i] = buffer;
```

or replace both lines (along with malloc) with

```
New->token[i] = strdup(buffer);
```

And it's better to replace `strtok` with `strtok_r` (strtok is not re-entrant).

Comment: Thank you, that solved the last word problem. Still, when the input is only made of two same words it still prints both. But I guess it's because I did the same in `New->token[i] = strtok(s, " ");` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The structure seems unnecessary.
This uses an array of pointers to store the tokens.
The input can be parsed with `strspn` and `strcspn`.
Unique tokens are added to the array of pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DIM 70

int main() {
    char* token[DIM] = { NULL};

    char s[DIM];
    char* buffer = s;
    int unique = 0, check = 0;
    int match = 0;
    int loop = 0;
    size_t space = 0;
    size_t span = 0;

    fgets(s, DIM, stdin);

    printf("The string is: %s\n", s);

    while ( unique < DIM && *buffer){//*buffer not pointing to zero terminator
        space = strspn ( buffer, " \n\t");//leading whitespace
        buffer += space;//advance past whitespace
        span = strcspn ( buffer, " \n\t");//not whitespace
        if ( span) {
            printf("\ntoken is: %.*s", (int)span, buffer );//prints span number of characters
        }
        match = 0;
        for ( check = 0; check < unique; ++check) {
            if ( 0 == strncmp ( token[check], buffer, span)) {
                match = 1;//found match
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( ! match) {//no match
            token[unique] = malloc ( span + 1);//allocate for token
            strncpy ( token[unique], buffer, span);//copy span number of characters
            token[unique][span] = 0;//zero terminate
            ++unique;//add a unique token
        }
        buffer += span;//advance past non whitespace for next token
    }

    printf("\n New string: ");
    for( loop = 0; loop < unique; ++loop) {
        printf(" %s", token[loop]);//print the unique tokens
    }
    printf("\n");
    for( loop = 0; loop < unique; ++loop) {
        free ( token[loop]);//free memory
    }
    return 0;
}
```